# Rails: replacement for _url helper for dynamic links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

I'm using Rails 2.3.9. and I have a model Project, for which I have a column url_name.
I added a catch-all route in routes.rb so I can handle incoming urls like:

www.../1-folder-nr

www.../2-folder-test

www.../3-rails
(you get the idea).

Before this I had project_books_url(@project) to use in controller and views.

But now I need something to replace that project_books_url(@project), something that will generate me the full url?

It's there something to act the same as the xxx_url helper so I can use it in the controller?

If anyone has any ideas or suggestion, they are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just write a helper method that generates whatever you want?

```
def project_books_path(project)
  "/#{project.to_param}"
end
helper_method :project_books_url
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the helper method and it helps in some part of the app, but there are still parts where I need the full url, not just /3-test, I need http://..../3-test to be returned, any ideas?

Comment: Presumably you can adjust the definition of the path to fit your needs, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method

```
 url_for(:controller :action)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for